# firefox jQuery syntax error by selecting input by name

Tags: jquery, firefox, input, syntax-error

I've got this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name='contact[email]'
```

Script:

```
var $element = $("input[name='contact["+element+"]'");
```

Error seems like, i've forgot closing `]` in the selector but i don't :D

So, where's the problem?

Thx!

Comment: what is the name of that tag?

Comment: does your tag name contains [] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing closing `]` and also escape meta characters

```
var $element = $("input[name='contact\\["+element+"\\]']");
```

Form [**DOCs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Comment: `var $element = $("[name*=" + element + "]");` this also did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var name='contact['+element+']';
 var $element = $("input[name='"+name+"']");
```